# vb.net for each private variable in me

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I'm working in VB.net and I want to create a generic ToString.
is there a way to do a "For Each" in "Me".

Sample

```
 Public Property Var1() As String {... get ... set ...}
 Public Property Var2() As String {... get ... set ...}
 Public Property Var2() As String {... get ... set ...}

 Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
     dim str as stringbuilder
     for each item in Me
        str.append(item.tostring())
     next
     return str
 End Function
```

The reason of my question its because some of my Variables can be null (nothing).
So with a generic like this, I can do

```
if item isnot nothing then
    str.append(item.tostring())
end if
```

maybe theres a better way???

tank you

Comment: You could use reflection, but you should not do! `ToString` should be as fast as possible and that would be the opposite.

Comment: Why do you want to write a `ToString()` using reflection? You know what your properties are, you know what they mean, just use those. When your class has many properties with big values do you really want ToString() to display all the information? Your `ToString` override needs to be specific to your class.

Comment: yeah, thats what I do, but I was thinking doing a code block, that I can paste on every toString (or a function like PrintElements()). so I dont need to rewrite every local variables, because sometimes I have lot of variables on my classe. That can be faster and can catch error like nothing.toString() if its needed.

Comment: this question has answers showing how to use reflection to iterate properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410807/reflection-iterate-objects-properties-recursively-within-my-own-assemblies-v

Comment: relfection seems interresting. Why do so said that I should not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using reflection with `GetFields`. Here you go:

```
Public Class [MyClass]
    Private a As String
    Private b As String

    Public Sub New(a As String, b As String)
        Me.a = a
        Me.b = b
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
        For Each item In [GetType]().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
             sb.Append(item.Name) _
               .Append("=") _
               .Append(item.GetValue(Me)) _
               .Append(" ")
        Next
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
```

If you want to display properties use `GetProperties`

Comment: Tank you, thats what I wanted.