# Deep search within a multidimensional object

Tags: c#

I have a complex class whose fields can be lists dictionaries and any other classes. Some basic data types are `int` , `bool`, `string` or some enums. I need to created a functions that takes an instance of that class and a string and return true or false depending if there is a mentioning of the string.

```
public class Record
  {
    public Dictionary<string,int> Counts { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,list<string>> Syns {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string,KeyValuePair<string,bool>> Stuff { get; set; }
    //etc 
  }
```

Here is what the method should do

```
   public static bool IsValuePresent(Object o, string keyword)
     {
       //cycle through all possible string values of o and check if keyword is present. 
       //return true if so, otherwise false
     }
```

possible call:

```
 Record record = dbAccess.GetCurrent();
 bool flag = IsValuePresent(record, "Name");
```

Remark: can use `ToJSON` but this will verify if `"name"` is present among names of of object properties, but it should only verify values.

Comment: Your code won't compile, as written - please post the real code for "Record", or at least a working example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use recursion and use System.Reflection.  Here is a good post:

[Reflection - Iterate object's properties recursively within my own assemblies (Vb.Net/3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410807/reflection-iterate-objects-properties-recursively-within-my-own-assemblies-v)

Look at:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in o.GetType().GetProperties())
```

Comment: I used that two, but it does not work very well with complex properties like `list` or `dictionary'. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: I just red your remark more carefully. Yes, the recursion is what I need to do if I don't want to use JSON. Is there a fast way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood, but I think you'll need to first reference the fields in your class

`record->field1` or `record.field1` (for statically allocated class)

I am assuming these fields are a dictionary class so you can then use one of the dictionary classes methods to locate your string.

```
record->field1.getindex("Name")
```

You can then wrap this entire procedure in your method and make it a method within your record class or make it an external method.  Below I use an internal method.

```
template <class T>
bool Record :: IsValuePresent(T listobject, string in) {

switch (typeof(listobject))
{
   case 'dictionary'
     if(record->field1.getindex(in) != -1)  // -1 meaning not present in this example
     {
       return false;
     } else return true;
   case 'list'
    // more code
   default: 
     return false;
}
```

}

The compiler should optimize the above method.

Comment: they are not all Dictionary classes, some maybe lists, arrays, or even other classes. I do not know in advance the structure of Record. I need to be able to discover it as I run IsValuePresent.

Comment: Then you can add a case switch statement (into the IsValuePresent method) that uses `typeid( )`.  I updated the code above.

Comment: Sorry, I used a c++ operator.  For C# you can use `typeof(MyObject).GetProperties()`